# How to append to python dictionary inside a function

Tags: python

I have  the following code:

```
def main():
   content = si.RetrieveContent()
   esx_vm = {}
   search_index = si.content.searchIndex
   for child in content.rootFolder.childEntity:
      if hasattr(child, 'vmFolder'):
         datacenter = child
         vmFolder = datacenter.vmFolder
         vmList = vmFolder.childEntity

         for vm in vmList:
            vmname = PrintVmInfo(vm)
            if vmname is not  None:
                hostname = vmname

                vm = si.content.searchIndex.FindByDnsName(None, hostname, True)
                try :
                    ESX = vm.runtime.host.name
                except :
                    pass

   esx_vm.update({ESX:hostname})
   print(esx_vm)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

The code is supposed to create a dictionary mapping `esx` to `vm` in the below format:

```
{'esx1': 'vm1'}
```

But I am getting only one key-value `{'esx1': 'vm1'}` and not all the `esx:vm` mappings. I am excepting to get:

```
{'esx1': 'vm1','esx2': 'vm2','esx3': 'vm3','esx4': 'vm4'}
```

and so on.

Any advise how to get the the correct values of the dictionary?

Comment: Python is all about indentation. Indent the line `esx_vm.update({ESX:hostname})` so it is executed in the inner loop (`for vm in vmList:`) and you are good.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to update ESX values inside "for loop". But its happening to be outside, that's why there is one key in the dict. Please add ESX key as part of for loop. Something like this (inside for loop),

```
try :
    ESX = vm.runtime.host.name
    esx_vm.update({ESX:hostname}) # Or, just, esx_vm[ESX]=hostname
except :
    pass
```